# Store Credentials in SOLR HTTPS request

Tags: solr

I need to make a https request to SOLR without having to manually input the username and password into the pop-up box. Is there any way to do this? Example below:

> http://localhost/solr/admin/authentication

gives me a credentials token

Turn this:

> http://localhost/solr/collectionX/select?q=PARTNO:1234

Into:

> http://localhost/solr/collectionX/select?q=PARTNO:1234&credentials=solr:authtoken

Comment: I thought that was just plain HTTP authentication - i.e. `https://username:password@localhost/solr/collectionX/select?...` should work. The "token" as you call it in the response from the `authentication` endpoint is a hashed version of the password and can't be used directly for authentication. You have to use the plain text password.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that doesn't work, but I used the below snippet to get a response without prompting for login details:

Dim fr As WebRequest
        Dim targetURI As New Uri(localhost/solr")
        fr = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(targetURI), WebRequest)
        fr.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("solr", "SolrRocks")
         Dim str As New StreamReader(fr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            Dim streamText As String = str.ReadToEnd()
Label1.Text = streamText